# Automatic order(quantity per day, days quantity). PHP Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have an order form like with inputs like:

- service
- quantity per day
- days quantity

And I need to create order, which should be launched a certain number of times a day, a certain number of days...

Which technology I can use for do this ? or maybe Ideas?

My project built on PHP Laravel 5.4 Framework.

Comment: can you show us some code and the things you already tried?

Comment: I don't know how I can do this... Before I thought use "Queue".
But can't find examples, can we set number of days ...

Answer (score 0):

You can create a command in laravel ([link](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/artisan#writing-commands)) to enter orders, checking if it meets the condition to be sent ...

This command would be executed by **CRONJOB** on your server ...